# Access UK date format issues

Tags: ms-access

I have an access table with columnd `orderDate` which is a date/time column.

I have the following query, which refuses to work. I am looking for orders received from Sep 1 onwards.

```
SELECT * FROM [tblInfo]
WHERE 
Format(OrderDate,'d/m/yyyy') >= Format(#01/09/2017#,'d/m/yyyy')
```

which works - but returns one result where the `orderDate = 09/05/2017 18:07:58`  which is obviously not what i am looking for - so it seems the format is still incorrect.

Using -

```
Format(OrderDate,'dd/mm/yyyy') >= Format(#01/09/2017#,'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

returns all orders from 2017 - so thats incorrect too.

Interestingly. the following format **works** in a web interface. but still not in the Access query interface:

```
OrderDate >= Format(#01/09/2017#,'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

What have I got wrong?

Thank you. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing string comparisons while you want to compare dates. You're better off just comparing the dates, and not creating formatted strings first.

```sql
SELECT * FROM [tblInfo]
WHERE 
OrderDate >= DateSerial(2017, 09, 01)
```

Also note: `#01/09/2017#` actually is the 9th of January 2017